# How to control background image transparency in android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, background

I use this tag to set background

```
android:background="@drawable/image_name"
```

how to make that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about changing the transparency of your background image.  The first is by modifying the XML layout and the second is programmically.

You can do it in **XML** by using the code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/image_name"
    android:alpha=".75"/>
```

Where `android:alpha=""` is your transparency with 1 as fully solid and 0 is completely transparent.  More information is at the [Android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha)
(This will also work with the background of your view if that's what you want)

You can also change the transparency of it programmically (assuming you are using an ImageView).

To do this you can use the following code for the background of your view

```
int transparency = 100;
mView.getBackground().setAlpha(transparency);
```

The transparency runs from 0 to 225 where 0 is transparent and 225 is solid.

Comment: when I do that, the background and all components (texts and buttons) have the same ttransparency

Answer (score 1):

```
int transparency = 51 //0-255 (51 is 20% transparent)
nameOfYourView.getBackground().setAlpha(transparency);
```